# Change only left offset of all elements by classname

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say I have a lot of elements with classname `.leftItem`, they all have different offset from the top of the document.

I want to set the **left** offset of all elements to zero. I've looked into jQuerys `offset()` method and it only takes arguments of `left` **and** `top`.

Thus,
`$('.leftItem').offset({top: $(.leftItem).offset().top}, left: 0});` brings all the elements to the same top offset and I only want to set the **left**.

What's the easiest way to accomplish this? Do I have to set an unique id of every element and store the value of each individual top-offset?

**EDIT:** I've tried using `$(this).offset().top` but it returns undefined.. I believe it is because I am using it inside a handler

```
$scope.onSwipeRight = function(){

      $(".leftFade").offset({ top: $(this).offset().top, left: 0});

}
```

Comment: Did you try leaving the top-argument out? `$('.leftItem').offset({left: 0});`

Comment: Yes that does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this` inside jQuery's `each()`:

```
$('.leftItem').each(function() {
    $(this).offset({top: $(this).offset().top, left: 0});
});
```

> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbgRxx

Comment: Retry. For some reason offset does not work properly on collections as many other methods do. You will have to iterate over your collection.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use JS to do this? Maybe you could try using CSS and try the following:

```
.leftItem {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vyskxsdL/)